# How can I customize Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android?

Tags: android, facebook

recently I have been working on Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android.
While everything was done smoothly, I found the following issue.

- When the user presses a facebook Login button on a device where native Facebook app is not installed, a webview login activity appears. After logging in, the login page appears again even when the app requests user's permissions. (This is a known issue according to Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/333926600053215)

So, until Facebook fixes this issue, what I want to do is to detect whether the user has FB app installed on his device, and if not I want to show my customized webview that handles login process.

Since I have all the source codes in Facebook library project, I think I can customize that but the question is, how should this be done?

If I make a change on one of those files in the library projects, will it be automatically applied to the main project that uses this library project? What would be an efficient way to customize the facebook library project?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and partially solved it: roughly, i attempt to obtain login with publish permissions, if it's rejected then the fb application's installed and then i request read-only then publish, if it's not rejected then you get the login with publish permissions coming up right after it and you're good to go.

problems with this solution:

1) 3 user interactions instead if 2 if the fb app's installed.

2) bug if cancelling the login with a webview (a second one appears), though i think this one's solveable, i didn't have time to try.

sorry for quick/curt reply.